# Recortar imagen en circulo

Tags: c#

He intentado recortar una imagen en circulo, pero nomas he encontrado la forma de recortarlo en cuadrado.

```
static Bitmap LoadImage()
    {
        return (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile( @"e:\Tests\d_bigImage.bmp" );
    }

    static void TestBigImagePartDrawing()
    {
        using( var absentRectangleImage = LoadImage() )
        {
            using( var currentTile = new Bitmap( 256, 256 ) )
            {
                currentTile.SetResolution(absentRectangleImage.HorizontalResolution, absentRectangleImage.VerticalResolution);

                using( var currentTileGraphics = Graphics.FromImage( currentTile ) )
                {
                    currentTileGraphics.Clear( Color.Black );
                    var absentRectangleArea = new Rectangle( 3, 8963, 256, 256 );
                    currentTileGraphics.DrawImage( absentRectangleImage, 0, 0, absentRectangleArea, GraphicsUnit.Pixel );
                }

                currentTile.Save(@"e:\Tests\Tile.bmp");
            }
        }
    }
```

¿Habra una forma de editar ese codigo para que funcione en circulo?

Gracias de antemano

Comment: No hay una forma sencilla de recortar una imagen en un círculo. TextureBrush podría servirte.